# change the net tcp port of a wcf service running on windows service

Tags: wcf, tcp, windows-services

I'm using this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

How do I change the port or specify a port and open it and all the other good stuff needed to access the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734786.aspx or at least finish reading of your link up to 13th point in list, where configuration file is provided

according to [standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator), URL consists of:

`protocol` :// `hostname` [: `portnumber`] [`/path`]

so, you need to change 8080 in your config to proper port

`<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>`

Comment: that's odd, I read the 13th point and I didn't read anything about port specified having ANY affect on open ports and such. Odd also that the second and third reading didn't change that perspective. maybe your internet page is different from mine.

Comment: `<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>` :8080 is the port

Comment: Please update the answer to include that changing the baseAddress or the endpoint address will, in fact, change the port also. it's just rolled in there by magic. thx